# 1TB hard drive issues

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have a problem with my secondary 1 TB hard drive. When I copy large amounts of video files to it for storage it "disappears" after a bit. I have to re-boot to see the drive again. The drive always is very slow to access. Windows 7. This is a custom built computer for video editing in HD.

Comment: That dosen't sound very good. You might want to get that drive checked out with something like [gsmartcontrol](http://gsmartcontrol.berlios.de/home/index.php/en/Home) .

Comment: Reboot, or plug the drive in again?

Comment: maybe you need to buy another hardrive

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with either a hard drive, SATA interface, or power supply. How to diagnose:

1. Install SMART hard drive monitor. I suggest [Argus Monitor](http://www.argusmonitor.com/en/), it works very well for me. This program will let you see if your hard drive is about to fail. It also can be used to check if your hard drive overheats.
2. Install software that displays voltage sensors values. Either use one that came with your computer/motherboard, or install a generic one. I suggest [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php). Make sure 12V rail does not dip much below 12V. If voltages are unstable, it means that your power supply does not supply enough "juice" for your hard drive. If this is your problem, and your power supply has several 12V rails (check the manual), you can try connecting this hard disk to a different 12V rail. Most check power supplies do not have more than one 12V rail.
3. Check Windows event log, it may provide *some* information, if this is a software and not a hardware problem. However, if this is a hardware failure, you will probably see something generic, like "hard drive disconnected".